# How do I get the number by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Now,I have this Series:

```
0    a,b
1    a
2    c
3    b,a,d
4    a,c
dtype: object
```

so,How can I get the series(I try to use sr.value_counts(),but no valid) like this:

```
a    4
b    2
c    2
d    1
dtype: int64
```

thanks

Comment: How did you create that series?

Comment: Does `b,a,d` in `3    b,a,d`  represent a string?It looks like you are trying to get the string counts in the dataframe.

Comment: yes,it represent a string

Answer (score 3):

You can split and expand the string, e.g.:

```
>>> sr.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
a    4
b    2
c    2
d    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
your_series.str.split(",").apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()
#a    4
#b    2
#c    2
#d    1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

```
sr.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

---

**Option 2**

```
sr.str.get_dummies(',').sum()
```